# Deserialization using ISerializable interface

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, deserialization

I have a WCF returning an object which again contains multiple objects in JSON format. In the client while deserializing this object, I am implementing ISerializable interface to customize the deserialization. For that, I have a custom constructor which gives me SerializationInfo and StreamingContext. But while debugging, I don't see any data in SerializationInfo object.

Please note that I am not using GetObjectData method in WCF to serialize the response and just using default serialization.

Am I wrong in assuming that SerializationInfo object should have all the response objects without doing "GetObjectData" in WCF? Or do I have to manually add all response objects to SerializationInfo in WCF before returning the response?

Comment: The documentation for the `SerializationInfo` class mentions that `GetObjectData` populates this data structure, but it doesn't mention anything else:  "This class is used by objects with custom serialization behavior. The GetObjectData method on either ISerializable or ISerializationSurrogate populates the SerializationInfo store with the name, type, and value of each piece of information it wants to serialize." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ...and from the documentation on custom serialization:  "When GetObjectData is called during serialization, you are responsible for populating the SerializationInfo provided with the method call. ... You have the freedom to decide which member variables are added to the SerializationInfo, provided that sufficient data is serialized to restore the object during deserialization. Derived classes should call the GetObjectData method on the base object if the latter implements ISerializable." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx)